# How i can use the text file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file-io

i want to read the text file and show it on edit-text but I don't know where to place the text file in project and after that, how can I call the text file for read and write purposes?

I am getting the error `No such file or directory`.

This is what i have done so far:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     txtEditor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox);
     readTextFile("test.txt");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public String readTextFile(String fileName) {

      String returnValue = "";
      FileReader file = null;

      try {
        file = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          returnValue += line + "\n";
        }
        txtEditor.setText(reader.toString());
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      } finally {
        if (file != null) {
          try {
            file.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore issues during closing 
          }
        }
      }
      return returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you provided no path for the text file. You have to place it at the root of your project.

You should remove the line `txtEditor.setText(reader.toString());` in the method `readTextFile` for two reasons :

- `reader.toString()` won't give you the text contained in the reader but it will prints the memory address of the object (`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()`) because the `toString()` method is direclty inherited from the `Object` class.
- the method already returns the text contained in the file.

---

So create a variable that holds this string and set it to the `EditText`.

```
String text = readTextFile("test.txt");    
txtEditor.setText(text);
```

Comment: or he can chage txtEditor.setText(reader.toString()); with txtEditor.setText(returnValue);